# Hive table property to consider consecutive delimiters as one delimiter

Tags: hive, hiveql, regexserde

```
jan 18 "value1 is null"
feb  4 "value1 is null"
```

in the above dataset there is consecutive delimiters between the 1st and 2nd column in second row how to handle consecutive delimiters as one delimiter.

Comment: The example is not clear

Comment: `jan 18 "value1 is null" \n
feb  4 "value1 is null"`

Comment: I can see the example but I don't see 2 columns and I don't see any delimiter. I can guess that you want CSV serde in order to treat `"value1 is null"` as a single value.

Comment: it is 2 rows and 3 columns

Comment: there 2 space between feb and 4, as 4 is a single digit in the second row

Comment: space delimiter might be confusing let me put it this way. `jan,18,"value1 is null" \n feb,,4,"value1 is null"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create external table mydata 
(
    c1 string
   ,c2 string
   ,c3 string
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
with serdeproperties ('input.regex' = '(".*?"|.*?)\\s+(".*?"|.*?)\\s+(".*?"|.*?)')
location '/user/hive/warehouse/mydata'
;
```

---

```
select * from mydata;
```

---

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| mydata.c1 | mydata.c2 |    mydata.c3     |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| jan       |        18 | "value1 is null" |
| feb       |         4 | "value1 is null" |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: thanks friend. is this the only way possible or by using 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'  can we get it. because I have got 75 columns in my data set.

Comment: MultiDelimitSerDe seems to handle only a fixed length delimiter.